# Print right answer if its selected and print selected answer if wrong with right answer

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to print if user selected right answer, if right then print " you selected right: your selected answer is :.... " if user choose not right answer then to print his selected answer and the correct answer. All questions is in database. My function checks answers but scan it without spaces and when spaces is in the choices and user selects correct answer it says its wrong. My answers code:

```html
<?php 

require_once 'templates/header.php';

$servername2 = "localhost";
$username2 = "root";
$password2 = "";
$db2 = "user_login";

$conn2 = new mysqli($servername2, $username2, $password2, $db2);
$kat = $_SESSION['kategorija'];
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM questions where category_id=$kat";
$results = $conn2->query($sql2);

$s=0;
$count = $_SESSION['count'];
$kategorija = $_SESSION['kategorijaName'];
?>

<body>
    <div class="container" style="margin-top:100px;">
        <div class="row" style=" margin-bottom:30px;">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="" style="text-align: -webkit-center;
    font-size: 2em;
    letter-spacing: 2px;    
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: Open Sans, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #4B4B4C;">
                    <?php echo $kategorija; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <?php
 $teisingi = 0;
 foreach($results as $result){
   
        $s++;
       
        $cAnswer = $result['correctAnswer'];

        if (isset($_POST['answers'.$s.''])){
        $answers2 = $_POST['answers'.$s.''];
        }else $answers2 = NULL;
       
        echo '<div class="borderis"> '.$result['question'].'</div>';

        if ($answers2 != NULL ){
            if($answers2 == $result['answer'.$cAnswer.''] ){
                
                        echo '<div style="margin-bottom:20px; margin-top:10px; color: #40a240;
                        letter-spacing: 2px;"> Jūsų pasirinktas atsakymas yra teisingas: '; 
                        echo ''.$answers2.'</div>';
                        $teisingi++;
                        
                    }else{
                        echo '<div style="margin-top:10px;  margin-bottom:10px; color:red; letter-spacing: 2px;"> Jūsų pasirinktas atsakymas yra neteisingas: '; 
                        echo ''.$answers2.'</div>';
                        echo '<div style="margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:20px; color: #40a240;
                        letter-spacing: 2px; "> Teisingas atsakymas yra: '.$result['answer'.$cAnswer.''].'</div>';
                        
                    } 
        }else {
            echo '<div style="margin-top:10px;  margin-bottom:20px;  letter-spacing: 2px;"> Neatsakytas </div>'; 

        }
    }
    ?>
                    <div class="row" style=" padding-top: 20px; margin-bottom:40px;">
                        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                            <a href="start-quiz.php" class="btn btn-success btn-block" id="start_btn"> Grįžti į testus </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" style="text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 3px !important;
    font-size:1.3em !important;
    font-weight: 600 !important;
    text-align: -webkit-center;
    border: 3px solid #4B4B4C;
   "> Jūs atsakėte teisingai
                            <?php echo $teisingi.'/'.$count ?> </div>

                    </div>

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>

<script>
</script>
<?php

    $conn2->close();?>
```

And there is my questions code where I print questions:

```html
<?php



 require_once 'templates/header.php';
 ?>  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script> <?php

$servername2 = "localhost";
$username2 = "root";
$password2 = "";
$db2 = "user_login";

$kat = $_POST['category'];
$_SESSION['kategorija'] = $kat;


$conn2 = new mysqli($servername2, $username2, $password2, $db2);

$query2 = "SET NAMES utf8";
$stmt2 = $conn2->prepare($query2);
$stmt2->execute();

$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM questions where category_id= $kat";
$sql3 = "SELECT category_name FROM categories where id= $kat";
$result2 = $conn2->query($sql2);
$result3 = $conn2->query($sql3);
while($row2 = $result3->fetch_assoc()) {
$kategorija = $row2['category_name'];
}

$i=0;
?>

<div class="container">


<?php






if ($result2->num_rows > 0) {



    ?>

    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="margin-top: 100px;">
    <div class="" style="text-align: -webkit-center;
    font-size: 2em;
    letter-spacing: 2px;

    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: Open Sans, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #4B4B4C;"> <?php echo $kategorija; ?>
</div></div></div>
    <form action="atsakymai.php" method="post" id="quiz" style="margin-top:100px;" >
    <?php



    while($row = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
       $label1 = $row['answer1'];
       $label2 = $row['answer2'];
       $label3 = $row['answer3'];
       $label4 = $row['answer4'];
       $z = 1;
       while ( $z<=4 ){
        $row['answer'.$z.''] =  preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $row['answer'.$z.'']);
       
    
        $z++;
       }

        echo '<div class="row">';
        echo '<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">';
        echo '<div class="borderis">'.$row['question'].'</div><br>';
        $i++;

       echo '<fieldset id="group" >';

        echo '<label for="'.$row['answer1'].'"><input type="radio"  id="'.$row['answer1'].'" name="answers'.$i.'" value="'.$row['answer1'].'" class="mygtukai"> <bled></bled>
        <span>'.$label1.'</span></label>'.'<br>';


        echo '<label for="'.$row['answer2'].'"><input type="radio" id="'.$row['answer2'].'"name="answers'.$i.'" value="'.$row['answer2'].'"> <bled></bled>
        <span>'.$label2.'</span></label>'.'<br>';

        echo '<label for="'.$row['answer3'].'"><input type="radio" id="'.$row['answer3'].'"name="answers'.$i.'" value="'.$row['answer3'].'"> <bled></bled>
        <span>'.$label3.'</span></label>'.'<br>';

        echo '<label style="margin-bottom:15px;" for="'.$row['answer4'].'"><input type="radio" id="'.$row['answer4'].'"name="answers'.$i.'" value="'.$row['answer4'].'"> <bled></bled>
        <span>'.$label4.'</span></label>'.'<br>';

    echo '</fieldset>';
      echo '</div></div>';



    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

?>



    


    <div id="progressbar"></div>
<div id="percentage"></div>


    <input type="submit" value="Pateikti atsakymus" name="result" class="qSubmit" id="qSubmit" />


</form>


<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    var names = {};
    $(':radio').each(function() {
        names[$(this).attr('name')] = true;
    });
    var count = 0;
    $.each(names, function() {
        count++;
    });


      $("#qSubmit").click(function(){
   if ($(':radio:checked').length !== count) {
    event.preventDefault();
              alert("Atsakykite į visus klausimus!");
               }

    });
});

</script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#progressbar').progressbar({
        value: 0
    });

    $('[name*=answers]').click(function() {
        var totalChecked = 0;
        var totalRadioGroups = 0;
        var previousName = '';
        $.each($('[name*=answers]'), function(index, value) {
            var radioName = $(this).attr('name');
            var radioId = this.id;

            if (previousName != radioName) {
                totalRadioGroups++;
            }
            if ($('#' + radioId).is(':checked')) {
                totalChecked++;
            }
            previousName = radioName;
        });
        var percentage = (totalChecked / totalRadioGroups) * 100;
        $('#progressbar').progressbar('value', percentage);
        $('#percentage').html(percentage.toFixed(2) + "%");
    });

});


</script>




<?php
$_SESSION['count'] = $i;
$_SESSION['kategorijaName'] = $kategorija;
$conn2->close();
$stmt2->close();
?>
```